# Why Bash Parent Process exits before its child when command is used in background in a Bash script?

Tags: linux, shell, process

Let's say I have for the following simple bash script:
`test_bg.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
ping www.google.ro &> /dev/null &
```

If I execute it directly via `./test_bg.sh` and do a `ps -ef` after, I see that the process  `ping www.google.ro` is inherited by systemd (PID 1), which means that its parent exited, not waiting for it to finish, so I am getting an orphan process:

```
UID          PID    PPID    PGID     SID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root           1       0       1       1  0 Jan07 ?        00:00:21 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --system --deserialize 21
...
...
...
nimus     461772       1  461771  458695  0 18:59 pts/1    00:00:00 ping www.google.ro
```

This, of course happens if I use `/bin/bash -c "ping www.google.ro &> /dev/null &"` too.

If I execute the code in the script without `&`, so the code looking like this in a `test_fg.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ping www.google.ro &> /dev/null
```

the `ps -efj --forest` would look like this:

```
UID          PID    PPID    PGID     SID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
nimus     458695  458596  458695  458695  0 17:02 pts/1    00:00:00  |       \_ -bash
nimus     461907  458695  461907  458695  0 19:02 pts/1    00:00:00  |           \_ /bin/bash ./test_fg.sh
nimus     461908  461907  461907  458695  0 19:02 pts/1    00:00:00  |               \_ ping www.google.ro
```

So the forked process `/bin/bash ./test_fg.sh` that further fork() again and exec() the `ping www.google.ro`  is still alive.

And, of course executing `ping www.google.ro &> /dev/null &` directly from my main bash process that is the Session Leader I would get:

```
[nimus@localhost ~]$ ping www.google.ro &> /dev/null &
[1] 462091
```

```
[nimus@localhost ~]$ ps -efj --forest
UID          PID    PPID    PGID     SID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      458581  351997  458581  458581  0 17:02 ?        00:00:00  \_ sshd: nimus [priv]
nimus     458596  458581  458581  458581  0 17:02 ?        00:00:00  |   \_ sshd: nimus@pts/1
nimus     458695  458596  458695  458695  0 17:02 pts/1    00:00:00  |       \_ -bash
nimus     462091  458695  462091  458695  0 19:10 pts/1    00:00:00  |           \_ ping www.google.ro
```

So, why does the `ping www.google.ro` process ends up inherited by `Systemd PID 1` when it is executed in background `&` in script?

Comment: because you're not `wait`ing for it.

Answer (score 0):

When you start a process in the background (using `&`), it starts executing concurrently with its parent.  Since your script does not have anything else to do, it `exit`s and the orphaned process is adopted by `init`.  When you do not use `&`, the parent `wait`s for the child to finish, suspending itself. and you see the script as parent.  In the latter case, parent will show up as suspended/sleeping.

Answer (score 0):

The process running the script exits, **because it reaches the end** of the script.
It reaches the end of the script, because the command is run in the background with `&`.